# Yandex map не дружит с Ajax

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

На сайте страницы подгружаются с помощь Ajax, на одной из [страниц](http://interrol.by/Kontakti) есть Yandex map.

В общем, при загрузке страницы всё работает, но при переходе на неё с другой (по ajax) карта не запускается.

Что делать? (У меня была идея завернуть карту каким-то образом в iframe, но эта идея мне не понравилась.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@Станислав Далинин](/users/6975/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD), карта должна явно инициализироваться для ее показа. На самом деле именно это происходит во всех демо-скриптах:

```
var map = new ymaps.Map ("map", {
        center: [55.76, 37.64], 
        zoom: 7
    });
```

насколько понимаю, достаточно просто вызывать аналог при каждой новой отрисовке карты (если элемент с ней не хранится в кэше между посещениями страницы).